# Can't set ODBC source at runtime from an ASP.NET Core app hosted in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, odbc, iis-8

I have an ASP.NET Core application targeted to use Full .NET Framework 4.6 that contains a part of code where I Create a DSN in ODBC called in Startup.cs:

```
...
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.ConfigureSqlContext(Configuration);
            services.CrearDSN(Configuration);
...
```

And in ServiceExtensions.cs:

```
private const short ODBC_ADD_DSN = 1; //' Add user data source 
       private const short ODBC_CONFIG_DSN = 2; //' Configure (edit) data source 
       source 
        private const int vbAPINull = 0;

    public static void CrearDSN(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
            {
                //DSNBaseOperativa = Replace(Left((My.Settings.Servidor & My.Settings.BaseDatos & Application.ProductName), 32), "\", "") 'El nombre tiene como maximo 32 caracteres.

            //IOptions<ConnectionODBC> odbcsettings;

            string Driver = "SQL Server"; 
            int ReturnValue;
            string Attributes;

            //string name = config["SQLconnection:Server"] + config["SQLconnection:Database"] + "InteliBS";
            string name = config["SQLConnection:Server"] + config["SQLConnection:Database"] + "InteliBS";
            string DSNBaseOperativa =  name.Length > 32 ? name.Substring(0, 32).Replace( "\\", "") : name.Replace("\\", ""); //'El nombre tiene como maximo 32 caracteres.

            Attributes = "SERVER=" + config["SQLConnection:Server"] + "\0";
            Attributes += "DESCRIPTION=Temp DSN" + "\0";
            Attributes += "DSN=" + DSNBaseOperativa + "\0";
            Attributes += "DATABASE=" + config["SQLConnection:Database"] + "\0";
            //'To show dialog, use Form1.Hwnd instead of vbAPINull. 
            ReturnValue = SQLConfigDataSource(vbAPINull, ODBC_ADD_DSN, Driver, Attributes); //TODO: Poder regresar el valor en debug o pararlo en caso 0
            if (ReturnValue != 0){
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Se ha cargado un DSN de ODBC: " + DSNBaseOperativa, "INFO");
                config["ConnectionODBC:DSN"] = DSNBaseOperativa;
                config["ConnectionODBC:Description"] = "Temp DSN";
                config["ConnectionODBC:Server"] = config["SQLConnection:Server"];
                config["ConnectionODBC:Database"] = config["SQLConnection:Database"];
                config["ConnectionODBC:Userid"] = config["SQLConnection:Userid"];
                config["ConnectionODBC:Password"] = config["SQLConnection:Password"];

                services.Configure<ConnectionODBC>(config.GetSection("ConnectionODBC"));
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("No se pudo crear un DSN de ODBC", "INFO");
            }

        }

// Use DllImport to import the Win32 SQLConfigDataSource function.
        [DllImport("ODBCCP32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        private static extern int SQLConfigDataSource(int hwndParent, int ByValfRequest, string lpszDriver, string lpszAttributes);
```

Maybe are you wondering why I'm trying to configure an ODBC instead a regular SQL connection string. The reason is a legacy library that requires that in some parts of the application that I won't explain. Everything else use Entity Framework as usual.

When I run my application from Visual Studio 2017 using IISExpress, works like a charm. It creates an ODBC User Source with no problem in case doesn't exist.

But when I try to host it an IIS server on Windows Server 2012 R2, it doesn't work. Is there a restriction from IIS8 that prevents that?

Comment: While hosting in IIS have you tried with `Enable 32 bit Applicaiton` setting turned on for Application Pool?

Comment: No. How it can be related if my app is 64-bit?

Comment: Because your DSN may be created using 32 bit ODBC. https://www.firehousesoftware.com/webhelp/FHCADMonitor/Content/InstallationGuide/03_Create64-bitODBCDataSource.htm

Comment: I enabled it but it doesn't do anything, 64-bit/32-bit ODBC sources are the same.

Comment: Is the SQLConfigDataSource return value true?

Comment: I have no way to know. Logs just informs where a request fails in an mvc application in a method or controller, but have no information what happens in Startup.cs or ServiceExtension classes.
The only thing that suspects that DSN is not created is because it doesn't found a string that's because throw an exception to lead a 500. Also I'm checking myself in ODBC Sources and is not added,

Comment: You should check for errors. Use debug, traces, events, file, whatever. If SQLConfigDataSource returns false then you must call SQLInstallerError to determine the cause. Chances are there's a security issue or the IIS running user (pool) hasn't enough rights to write a DSN. You use ODBC_ADD_DSN, have you tried ODBC_ADD_SYS_DSN?

Comment: I actually check for errors by changing to Development environment, that's the way I noticed where code throws exception, but nothing about SqlConfigDataSource or nothing at Startup. 
Checking pool user permissions perhaps is a good idea.Let me check it out.

Comment: @SimonMourier I selected another user in the application pool for this application in IIS and worked. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The user as whom IIS was running did not have the necessary permissions.

Selecting a different user from the application pool for this application resolved the issue.